# prepareForSegue collectionView using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using collectionView and I want to send selected cell data to a second controller

To fetch json data from server, I'm using alamofire:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var datas: JSON = []
    let brandSegueIdentifier = "showBrandSegue"

func getData() {
    let url = "http://192.168.3.16/dbo/data4.json"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                self.datas = json
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                print("JSON: \(json)")
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
}
```

number of items:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return datas.count
}
```

cell for item:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("brandCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BrandCollectionViewCell

    cell.data = self.datas[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

size of items:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let itemWidth = 100
    let itemHeight = 100
    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
}
```

segue:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, selectedItemIndex: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(brandSegueIdentifier, sender: self)
}
```

prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == brandSegueIdentifier {
        if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForCell(sender as! BrandCollectionViewCell) {
            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! BrandViewController
            if (self.datas[indexPath.row]["brandName"].string != nil) {
                destination.brandLabel.text = self.datas[indexPath.row]["brandName"].stringValue
                print(self.datas[indexPath.row]["brandName"].stringValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I'm going to send the data into another view controller, using prepareForSegue, I'm getting error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

but when I close this line below, the error won't show up:

```
destination.brandLabel.text = self.datas[indexPath.row]["brandName"].stringValue
```

please help me if I'm using wrong method. Let me know if you need more data to have a better overview the problem.

Comment: You are treating `sender` as a cell, but it will be your view controller, because you are sending `self` as the sender when you perform the segue. You can pass the `NSIndexPath` as the sender and the downcast sender to NSIndexPath and access the `item` property (row is for tables)

Comment: can you give the solution code? I'm still confused about collectionView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, selectedItemIndex: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(brandSegueIdentifier, sender: self)
}
```

the sender should be the cell but not the view controller itself, since you want to parse the sender to a cell in the prepareForSegue method, so it should be:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, selectedItemIndex: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(selectedItemIndex);
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(brandSegueIdentifier, sender: cell);
}
```

Comment: there is error `Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type '[NSIndexPath]'` 

in `if (self.datas[indexPath]["brandName"].string != nil) {`

Comment: do you mean `self.datas[indexPath.row]` ?

Comment: if I use `self.datas[indexPath.row]` an error occured `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: that means the object at the index of indexPath.row is nil, make sure you set the collectionView's dataSource right.

Comment: but when I close this line `destination.brandLabel.text = self.datas[indexPath.row]["brandName"].stringValue` and then I print it in console like this `print(self.datas[indexPath.row]["brandName"].stringValue)`, it show up the right value from the cell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108248/discussion-between-lamfete-and-mudontire).

Answer (score 1):

In your performSegue you are passing the object of the viewcontroller itself. In your prepareForSegue you are trying to get the indexPath of the ViewController which is returning nil.

Instead in your prepareForSegue, you can do this
let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForSelectedRow?

Comment: the problem is this line of code : `destination.brandLabel.text = self.datas[indexPath.row]["brandName"].stringValue`. When close this line, the error won't show up.

Comment: Collection view doesnt have "indexPathForSelectedRow"